# I have installed WAMP Server on 192.168.1.104 System, How to connect MySql From other System Ex.: 192.168.1.5

Tags: php, mysql, wamp, mysql-connect

Thanks in advance.

I have Installed WAMP Server on System 4(192.168.1.104). I can Connect MySql DB from System 4 Local host.

```
//Code:
if (!mysql_connect('localhost','root', '')){
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
```

The Connection is working Fine.

Now i am trying to Connect System 4 Database From Another Machine.

```
//Code:
if (!mysql_connect('192.168.1.104','root', '')){
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
```

i am receiving This Error in Browser

> Warning: mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: Host 'Laptop' is
>   not allowed to connect to this MySQL server in
>   D:\xampp\htdocs\bigben_new\testDB.php on line 7 Could not connect:
>   Host 'Laptop' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server

Please Give a solution. and thanks in Advance.

Comment: Use [`GRANT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/grant.html) like `GRANT ALL ON TO *.* 'remoteuser'@'yourotherhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password'` - and don't forget to `FLUSH PRIVILEGES` afterwards. You could use `root` but I wouldn't do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to allow access to your `phpMyAdmin` on `'192.168.1.104'` from `'192.168.1.5'` or from all 127.0.0.1

You can refer below post.

[how to give access of PhpMyAdmin](http://abuhawa.wordpress.com/2009/01/07/restrict-phpmyadmin-access-to-only-internal-private-ip-address/)

Answer (score 1):

Simple:

```
GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO rkaartikeyan@192.168.1.104 IDENTIFIED BY 'rkaartikeyanpasswd';
```